# SUM of difference in values

Tags: ms-access, sum, multiple-columns

I need to query in MS Access the difference in value of a column to 8 and only if it is greater than 8.

So if I have a column of numbers 1-10, I want to query the sum of all the value's differences from 8. So the result of the query for the below column would be 3. (9-8)+(10-8)

```
    SELECT Sum(([time1]-8)+([time2]-8)+([time3]-8)+([time4]-8)+([time5]-8)+([time6]-8)+([time7]-8)+([time8]-8)+([time9]-8)+([time10]-8)+([time11]-8)+([time12]-8)+([time13]-8)+([time14]-8)+([time15]-8)+([time16]-8)+([time17]-8)+([time18]-8)+([time19]-8)+([time20]-8)+([time21]-8)+([time22]-8)) AS Total
FROM tblTimeTracking
WHERE (((Month(([Day])))=Month(Now()))) AND ([time1]>8 AND[time2]>8 AND[time3]>8 AND[time4]>8 AND[time5]>8 AND[time6]>8 AND[time7]>8 AND[time8]>8 AND[time9]>8 AND[time10]>8 AND[time11]>8 AND[time12]>8 AND[time13]>8 AND[time14]>8 AND[time15]>8 AND[time16]>8 AND[time17]>8 AND[time18]>8 AND[time19]>8 AND[time20]>8 AND[time21]>8 AND[time22])  ;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT Sum([Value]-8) As SumOfVal
FROM table
WHERE [Value]>8
```

Edit re complete change in original question.

It is not clear what you want

```
 SELECT Sum(([time1]-8)+([time2]-8) ...
 WHERE [time1]>8 And Time2>8 ...
```

Time1>8 will exclude nulls, but if that is not what you are doing, you will need to consider:

```
 Nz([time1],0) + ...
```

Edit re comments

Something like:

```
 SELECT Sum(times) FROM
 (SELECT IIf(Time1>8,Time1-8,Time1) As times FROM Table
 UNION ALL
 SELECT IIf(Time2>8,Time2-8,Time2)  As times FROM Table) As b
```

`As b` is an alias: [Access SQL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-sql-from-clause-HA010276924.aspx#BM2)

UNION / UNION ALL: [View a unified result from multiple queries with a union query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/view-a-unified-result-from-multiple-queries-with-a-union-query-HA102749627.aspx?CTT=1)

Comment: will this work and how should it look based on the above updated code. I am summing multiple columns @Remou

Comment: That is quite an enormous change from your original post. It does not look like a normalized table.

Comment: If you only want to subtract 8 when the value is greater than 8, you are into a lot of IIfs unless you normalize your table with a union query.

Comment: yes. would i place a union all between them all? what is the "As b"

Comment: Yes, keep repeating until you have all the fields `UNION ALL ... Time3 ... UNION ALL ... Time10`. `As b` just means that I want to refer to the subquery that includes all those unions by the alias `b`.